# VS Code Extension: detection of new line in text editor

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

My goal is to replace a fragment of text in the document that matches the pattern after pressing enter. I haven't seen any events triggered directly by a specific key in vscode API docs, so I tried using external library:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import keys form 'ctrl-keys';

// lota stuff here

if((match = pattern.exec(lineText) !== null)
{
    const hanler = keys();
    hanler.add('enter', () =>
    {
        editor.edit(editBuilder =>
        {
            editBuilder.replace(new vscode.Range(start, end), replacementText);
        });
    });
}
```

After few different approaches I left the idea of key-triggered events and did a little debugging due to which I found out that vscode `TextDocument.lineAt().lineNumber` property treats an empty new line as a previous line which prevents me from detecting enter press by tracking lines in `onDidChangeTextEditorSelecton()` event.
Is there a way to bypass that line counting or should I try a way different approach?